# How do I create a temporary table with Informix with a data import from the root table and a filter criterion

Tags: sql, informix

I don't know how to create a SQL statement in Informix that creates a temporary table "temp_countries" based on an existing table "countries". I also want the data from the countries table to be imported into the temporary temp_countries table and I want to be able to set a filter criterion on the imported data, such as "where name = "germany"".

Is this possible with the Informix database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the The INTO TEMP clause:
REF: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=shortcuts-into-temp-clause

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT * FROM countries
WHERE name = "germany"
INTO TEMP temp_countries;
```